# How to rename the string dict when creating Numpy array from list of dict

Tags: python, numpy

Creating Numpy array from list of dict

```
list_dict=[{'a': 11.02, 'b': 2.69}, {"a": 21.4, "b": 66.69},
           {"a": 100,"b": 200}]
```

result in a structure as below

[image]

Out of curiosity, may I know how to change the word `dict` to something else.

For example, to `mat_struc' as shown in figure below

[image]

Comment: What is this GUI? MATLAB? When you create an array from a list of dictionaries, it has `dtype=object` (as shown in the display). You get the same dtype for the other ndarray `signalData`. The dtype class is documented here: [NumPy array dtype doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). The standard dtypes support ints, floats, strings, etc. `dtype=object` is used for other Python objects -- e.g., arrays, dictionaries, lists, sets. I don't know what a `mat_struct` is. Some how your GUI can differentiate the underlying object as `dict` or `mat_struct`.

Comment: Hi @kcw78, thanks for showing interest in this OP.  The screenshot is from Pycharm variable viewer. This is the output from  scipy-loadmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use PyCharm, so making an educated guess about what you are seeing. NumPy's arrays can handle most any data type (the "dtype"). The most common are floats, ints, strings, etc. There is an "object" dtype for other Python objects -- e.g. dictionaries, lists, sets, even other `np.arrays`. When you create arrays with the object dtype, I suspect PyCharm inspects the `type()` of an array object for the variable type in the viewer.

Here is the code to create arrays with many different object dtypes. Run in PyCharm and compare the printed output to the GUI display. For more help from PyCharm experts, add the `[pycharm]` tag to your question.

Note: I used "ragged" lists, tuples and arrays to get the object dtype. When they are the same length, NumPy will attempt to create an array with the appropriate dtype (string, int, float). See the last 3 examples in the code for this behavior.

Good luck, have fun!

```
import numpy as np

ndarr = np.array([[1., 2.],
                  [3., 4.]])
print('ndarr dtype:',ndarr.dtype,'\n')

recarr = np.array([('Aa', 1, 2.), 
                      ('Bb', 3, 4.)],
                     dtype=[ ('Str','S2'), ('Int',int), ('Real',float) ] )
print('recarr dtype:',recarr.dtype,'\n')

list_dict = [{'a': 11.02, 'b': 2.69}, {"a": 21.4, "b": 66.69},
             {"a": 100,"b": 200}]
arr_dict = np.array(list_dict)
print('arr_dict dtype:',arr_dict.dtype)
print('arr_dict[0] type:',type(arr_dict[0]),'\n' )

list_list = [ ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['A','B','C','D'], ['x','y','z'] ]
arr_list = np.array(list_list,dtype=object)
print('arr_list dtype:',arr_list.dtype)
print('arr_list[0] type:',type(arr_list[0]),'\n' )

list_tups = [ ('a','b','c','d','e'), ('A','B','C','D'), ('x','y','z') ]
arr_tups = np.array(list_tups,dtype=object)
print('arr_tups dtype:',arr_tups.dtype)
print('arr_tups[0] type:',type(arr_tups[0]),'\n' )

list_sets = [ set(['a','b','c','d']), set(['A','B','C','D']), set(['x','y','z']) ]
arr_sets = np.array(list_sets)
print('arr_sets dtype:',arr_sets.dtype)
print('arr_sets[0] type:',type(arr_sets[0]),'\n' )

list_arrs = [ np.array(['a','b','c','d']), 
              np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 
              np.array([5., 6., 7., 8.]) ]
arr_arrs = np.array(list_arrs, dtype=object)
print('arr_arrs dtype:',arr_arrs.dtype)
print('arr_arrs[0] type:',type(arr_arrs[0]),'\n' )

list_list1 = [ ['a','b','c'], ['A','B','C'], ['x','y','z'] ]
arr_list1 = np.array(list_list1)
print('arr_list1 dtype:',arr_list1.dtype)

list_tups1 = [ ('a','b','c'), ('A','B','C'), ('x','y','z') ]
arr_tups1 = np.array(list_tups1)
print('arr_tups1 dtype:',arr_tups1.dtype)

list_arrs1 = [ np.array(['a','b','c','d']), 
              np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 
              np.array([5., 6., 7., 8.]) ]
arr_arrs1 = np.array(list_arrs1)
print('arr_arrs1 dtype:',arr_arrs1.dtype)
```

Comment: Really appreciate for the time and effort. +1. I will have take in depth look once I get my system on